# listview asp page adds inline display none to listview html elements

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, listview, inline

I am dynamically creating a listview - the intention is to create a catalogue type product display on the page but I am experiencing unusual behaviour. The query returns data and writes it to the listview elements but those elements when rendered are appended with unrequired inline styles, in every case all elements have inline display none so I can only see the issue if I inspect the element via IE developer tools. Thinking it was my mistake I tried 6 different online examples - the code for one example is below and they all rendered with inline display none as well. I turned page validation off. I have set AutoEventWireup="true" and just in case there is an issue with the query I created a really simple select * from tbl query but that resolved nothing. I cannot think what might be causing this behaviour. Here is an example listview

```
          <asp:ListView ID="lv1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <div style="border:solid 2px #336699; width:20%;">
         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
      </div>
   </LayoutTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div style="border: solid 1px #336699;">
       <p><%# Eval("fn_prod_code")%></p>
      </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <AlternatingItemTemplate>
      <div style="border: solid 1px #336699; background-color: #dadada;">
         <%# Eval("fn_prod_code")%>
      </div>
   </AlternatingItemTemplate>
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
      No records found
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and here is part of the code retrieved via IE's developer toolbar inspect element option:

```
   <div style="border: 1px solid rgb(51, 102, 153); border-image: none; display: none;">
   <p>101FN1</p>
  </div>
```

When I look at the page source the listview code is shown WITHOUT the inline styles as if it is rendering OK.
You might notice  border-image: none; was also added though that isn't an issue. I really need to understand what might be causing the inline display: none to be written.  I'm using VS2013 and framework 4.

---

AMENDMENT

---

Having ripped the page code to pieces it would seem to be a conflict between the code rendering the listview and a jQuery function I have running  window.onload=getbridalbagprodlist;  If I turn this function off the listview display: none is not written as an unwanted inline style. So I guess I now need another way to call the function so the timing? doesn't conflict.

Not sure if it is relevant but here is the function: (Basically via the jQuery function it gets or sets session data and returns it to a div on the page)

```
function getbridalbagprodlist() {

    var h3secstore = "";

    if (!$.session.get('theaddlist')) {
        $("#prodlist").html("Bridal Bag is empty");
    }
    else {
        $("#prodlist").html($.session.get('theaddlist'));
    }
    var h3secstore = $.session.get('thetitstore');
    $("#prodviewed").html(h3secstore);


    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#structureoff").offset().top
    }, 2000);

    var sec = "";
    var sectitle = "";

    if (!$.session.get('theprodname')) {
        sectitle = "Flower Bands";
    }
    else { sectitle = $.session.get('theprodname') }



    if (!$.session.get('theprod')) {
        sec = "flowerbands";
    }
    else {sec = $.session.get('theprod'); }

    if (sec == "all" || sec == "") {
        $("#structureprod div").fadeIn(900);
    } else {
        $("#structureprod div").hide();
        $("#structureprod div." + sec).fadeIn(900);
    }


    if (!$.session.get('thetitstore')) {
        h3secstore = "";

    } else {
        h3secstore = $.session.get('thetitstore'); // + "<br />" + recall3;
    }


    $("#prodviewed").html(h3secstore);

    $('#viewprodname').text(sectitle);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

AMENDMENT 2.
A bitter lesson. It was the function getbridalbagprodlist() which caused the issue - the function should have used a session to display a list but the session at that state was null and I coded it to hide a div, within which, I later placed the listview without reviewing ALL the code controlling that section of the page, neither did I comment the original code so I overlooked it's effect on the page. Dahh to me and a red face.